# Video tag in web page

Tags: html

I want to display a video in my web page but I had just the sound, the version of google chrome is 47.Where is the problem ? Thanks.

```
<body>
 <video src="tut.mp4" width="640" height="320" controls></video>
</body>
```

Comment: Can you provide a link to this resource for direct access? If you inspect the `<video>` element with your developer tools, what is the computed width/height of it?

Comment: it works for me (Chrome 47): http://jsfiddle.net/kvebe7a0/1/

Comment: @sebastianbrosch Do you have a solution ?

Comment: Considering it works for him I don't know what you want him to solve.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is important you will use the HTML5 video tag appropriately:

```
<video width="640" controls>
  <source src="movie.mp4" type="video/mp4">
  <source src="movie.ogg" type="video/ogg">
  Your browser does not support HTML5 video.
</video>
```

As you see it is needed for browser support that you will also have the video's in mp4 as well ogg format.

If you have only the mp4 there are many free converters that can do the job for you.

If you want to be more browser friendly than add to the collection also the WebM format.

Also, for your information, note that the video tag support also some options as 'autoplay', 'controls' or both.

Autoplay: the video plays when page loads
Controls: Show the video controls as play, pause,....